# Como guardar los datos en variables de sesión para que no se pierda los datos al volver a la misma pagina

Tags: php

Esta parte es la consulta de la factura donde se filtra los producto que tiene cada factura

```
$idpedidos = $_GET['idpedidos'];

$registro = $pdo->query("SELECT * from productos, pedidos, usuarios , detalle_factura , departamento where pedidos.usuario_pedi = usuarios.cedula and pedidos.departamento = departamento.iddepartamento and pedidos.numero_factura = detalle_factura.numero_factura and  pedidos.idpedidos = '$idpedidos' and productos.codigo_inv=detalle_factura.id_producto ");
$registro2 = $registro->fetch();
```

y aka el contenido de la factura

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" action="editar_pedido.php" method="GET">
         <div class="form-group row">
         <input class="form-control input-sm"  type="hidden"  name="pedido_id" size="20" id="pedido_id" value="<?php echo $idpedidos;?>">

         <div class="col-sm-5">
          <button type="submit" name="datos" class="btn btn-success">Guardar Cambios </button>
  </form>
```

El problema que tengo es que mando los datos a un archivo php donde me valida si la cantidad aprobada es mayor a la cantidad pedida, si es así me manda una alerta con un mensaje pero si no me guarda normal los dados pero al cumplirse la condición me devuelve a la pagina anterior donde esta la factura pero al volver los datos cargados anteriormente en la factura se borran y no aparece ningún dato solo las etiquetas

¿Como puedo hacer que cuando vuelva a la anterior pagina y se queden cargados los datos y no se borren?

[image: e]
asi se vacio y me sale este error Notice: Undefined index: idpedidos in C:\xampp\htdocs\sss\Formularios\Administrador\pedidos\editar_facturacion.php on line 12 pero esa variable viene por el método get de otro archivo

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a SO en español. Edita la pregunta, e indica en texto el código que has intentado realizar. 
Así será mas fácil ayudarte, y evitarás que te cierren la pregunta por baja calidad.

Answer (score 0):

Para trabajar con sesiones puedes utilizar la variable superglobal `$_SESSION`. Las sesiones te permitirán almacenar datos para usuarios de manera individual usando un ID de sesión único.

Antes de trabajar con sesiones debes "habilitar" en el principio del documento el uso de estas, con la función `session_start();`. 
También puedes utilizar `session.auto_start`, para leer más sobre esto puedes ir a la documentación de PHP [aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start)

**Crear una variable de sesión**

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['count'])) {
  $_SESSION['count'] = 0;
} else {
  $_SESSION['count']++;
}
?>
```

En el ejemplo anterior se utiliza `isset()` para validar la existencia de la variable.

**Eliminar una variable de sesión**

```
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['count']);
?>
```

Puedes leer más sobre las sesiones [acá](https://www.php.net/manual/es/session.examples.basic.php)

> Las sesiones trabajan con algunas configuraciones del servidor, como el tiempo de vida entre otras.

Puedes leer más sobre la configuración [acá](https://www.php.net/manual/es/session.configuration.php)

Respecto a *Undefined index*, esto quiere decir que estás intentando acceder a la posición de un `array` que no existe, en este caso `$_GET` no tiene la clave `idpedidos`. Para validar eso puedes utilizar la función de php `isset()` antes de acceder al array.

```
if(isset($_GET['idpedidos'])){
// La variable existe, haz algo
}else{
// La variable no existe, controla la excepción 
}
```